# How to make and create animated stickers for telegram free?

Tags: telegram

I want to make animated sticker in telegram. But without using adobe after effects or stuff. Actually I wnat to export GIF to TGS . Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this answer is completely wrong, but after a bit of research, it seems that telegram stickers [are vector based](https://telegram.org/blog/animated-stickers), so you shouldn't be able to use any kind of images in them (also, requirement 7: [Creating Animated Stickers](https://core.telegram.org/animated_stickers)). If it were true that they're vector only, then you could only get cartoonish styled animations, like the ones you see in most of their sticker packs.
However, Telegram has a separate gif feature, which you may use instead